# Android save image internally (java)

Tags: java, android

in my android app (java) i want to save a bitmap to locale storage and then get the absolute path so another app (flutter app) can also retrieve this image using the absolute path.
what's the best way to do it ?

Comment: Check scooped storage

https://source.android.com/devices/storage/scoped

Comment: You should probably first know an absolute path before you can save the bitmap to it. But or this absolute path is private so other apss cannot use it or it is not readable for other apps. So paths will not help you. Use SAF ACTION_CRETAE_FILE and use the uri for others apps. All in all we dont know how you would tell other apps about paths and uries.